# keras image_load() in Django expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile

Tags: python, django, keras

I got this error **expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile** when i want load the image using image_load().Here is my Code

```
from django.db import models
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np

# Create your models here.


class Image(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='article_images')
    classified = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.classified

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img = load_img(self.picture, target_size=(224, 224))
        img_arr = img_to_array(img)
        to_pred = np.expand_dims(img_arr, axis=0)  # (1,299,299,3)
        print(to_pred.shape)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

error : 
**expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile**

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes solved it .You can check this project in my github here is the [link](https://github.com/MahmudulHassan5809/Django-React-Image-Classifier)

Comment: how exactly? what was the problem?

Comment: can you please explain how did you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was experimenting with different ways of getting file content from `ImageField`, but all of them failed. So I've solved it by:

1. saving the model first,
2. then doing classification (only after save `self.picture.path` is not `null`),
3. then updating the model again.

Like the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        img = load_img(self.picture.path, target_size(224, 224))
        img_array = img_to_array(img)
        to_pred = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
        prep = preprocess_input(to_pred)
        model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet')
        prediction = model.predict(prep)
        decoded = decode_predictions(prediction)[0][0][1]
        self.classified = str(decoded)
        Image.objects.filter(pk=self.id).update(classified=self.classified)
        print('success')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Classification failed: {e}")
```